# The topology of $S^2 \setminus \{ \text{points} \}$

Tags: general-topology

I am confusing about sphere minus points. [I mean $S^2 \setminus \{ points \}$]

First, , I understand $S^2$ $\setminus$ {North pole} homeomorphic $\mathbb{R}^2$. [I can understand this using sterographic projection]

Next, $S^2$ $\setminus$ {North pole, South pole} is a homeomorphic to Cylinder ($S^1 \times \mathbb{R}$), actually geometrically(I mean by drawing) I can understand this procedure. Of course I can explicitly find the homeomorphism.   [for example, intuitively [Why do we have $S^2-\{N,S\}\simeq S^1\times\mathbb{R}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1983685/why-do-we-have-s2-n-s-simeq-s1-times-mathbbr)    or constructing homeomorphism, [How can I prove that a cylinder is diffeomorphic to a twice-punctured $n$-sphere?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2530621/how-can-i-prove-that-a-cylinder-is-diffeomorphic-to-a-twice-punctured-n-sphere) ]

Now I want further, As a next step I tried to understand three points case.

---

I edit question in a following way.

Since $S^2 \setminus$ {three points}  is homotpoic to figure 8 (not homeomoprhic). I am concern with its homeomorphic shape.

Is there any name for $S^2 \setminus$ {three points}? I simply guess it is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus$ {two points}, but can not draw its shape in my head.

and how about its generalization?

$S^2 \setminus $ {more than three points} $\simeq ? $

Comment: A sphere minus $3$ points is not homeomorphic to a figure $8$, but it is homotopy equivalent to that space.

Comment: The sphere minus three points is **homotopy equivalent** to a figure eight. By the way, it doesn't matter which point you remove, or which two points. $S^2\setminus \{x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n\}$ choosing $n$ distinct points will return the same space, up to homomorphism, for any two ways to pick the $x_i.$

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip, Thomas Andrews, I see, I might mistype the note.

Comment: The sphere minus $n$ points, for $n>1$ is homotopy equivalent to $$\underbrace{S_1\vee S_1\vee\cdots\vee S_1}_{n-1\text{ times}}$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, Oh that's a good information! Thanks!